# When I called [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:], crashed in iOS10

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
- (void)registerCellCallBack:(id<CellCallBack>)callBack {
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < _dataSource.count; ++i) {
        id<CellCallBack> oldCallBack = _dataSource[i];
        if([callBack key] <= [oldCallBack key]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i < _dataSource.count) {
        [_dataSource insertObject:callBack atIndex:i];
    } else {
        [_dataSource addObject:callBack];
    }

    [self.table beginUpdates];
    [self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.table endUpdates]; //--crashed here called "NSInternalInconsistencyException(SIGABRT)"
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _dataSource.count;
}
```

The code which even was well in iOS9, crashed in iOS10, but not appear when I debug my code.

**Crash info:**

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The
>   number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7)
>   must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before
>   the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted
>   from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number
>   of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Comment: just remove begin updates and end updates. thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change as per below:

To

```
 [self.table reloadData];
```

From

```
 [self.table beginUpdates];
 [self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
 [self.table endUpdates]; //--crashed here called "NSInternalInconsistencyException(SIGABRT)"
```

Comment: yeah，I has replaced, but it’s not efficient.I just want to know what changes is maked in ios10.

Comment: so it is not ios 10 bug.

Comment: make sure for future, don't call reload before calling insert rows. otherwise it will cause an error saying not matching rows before inserting and after inserting.

Comment: and? when you replace with reloadData you break the table's animation

Comment: I have given answer as per question not for animation . And there are not mentioned for animation .